# Generalise a function to all Int types without overloading?

Tags: swift, integer, encoder

I am making a custom `Encoder`, and it turns out I need to call the exact same functions on `Int`, `Int8`, `Int16`, `Int32` and `Int64` (and unsigned variants thereof).

Is there a way to do this without writing the same function with a different argument type 10 times ? EG a protocol they would all conform to, something like that ?

Here is what they all look like, except for the type of `value` :

```swift
static func encode(_ value : Int8) -> Data {
    withUnsafeBytes(of: value.bigEndian) {Data($0)}
}
```

Comment: How about writing the static function in an extension for `FixedWidthInteger`?

Comment: @koropok That does sound like what I need, I'm going to try that. EDIT : Actually maybe I should write an extension of Data to add an initialiser that accepts a FixedWidthInteger ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with thanks to @koropok 's comment :

```swift
extension Data {
    init<T : FixedWidthInteger>(_ value : T) {
        self = Swift.withUnsafeBytes(of: value.bigEndian) {Data($0)}
    }
}
```

Then inside the encoder :

```swift
static func encode<T : FixedWidthInteger>(_ value : T) -> Data {
    Data(value)
}
```

Admittedly the function above is now so simple it probably doesn't even need to exist, although it might still be useful for encapsulation purposes.